# No muestra imágenes en ionic

Tags: imagen, ionic3, vscode

He hecho una App con ionic 3.

A la hora de probarla en el navegador no tengo ningún problema, todo funciona bien. Para probarlo desde el navegador utilizo `ionic serve -l`

Mi problema es el siguiente:
 A la hora de probar la app en mi dispositivo, hay unas imágenes que no me muestra y otras si.

Todas las imágenes tienen la misma extensión con lo cual no puede ser la extensión de la imagen (Como he dicho antes, alguna imagen si que la muestra).
Todas las imágenes están en el mismo directorio con lo cual la ruta tampoco es el problema.

Las imágenes las almaceno en `assets/imgs/`

El editor que utilizo es Visual Studio Code.

En el editor (la zona de explorador de documentos), al lado de cada imagen, me pone unas letras, en las imágenes que si que puedo ver me pone una 'U', en las imágenes que pone otra letra no se muestran.

[image: Captura de imágenes]

Un ejemplo del código de la imagen que no me muestra es el siguiente:

```
<img src="assets/imgs/compuertasemi.png" style="width: 12vh; height: 20vh" /><br>
```

Un ejemplo del código de la imagen que si que me muestra es el siguiente:

```
<img style="height: 10vh;" src="assets/imgs/logoriegosalz.png" (click)="openLink()"/>
```

A la hora de generar el apk para instalarlo en mi dispositivo lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
ionic cordova resources
ionic cordova build android
```

No se si el problema está en el compilador que no me "añade" las imágenes al apk.

He leído que podría ser por la ruta de las imágenes pero tampoco, todas las imágenes las incluyo con

```
<img src="assets/imgs/nombreImagen.png" styles="..." ... >
```

Así es como se ve mi pantalla donde no me muestra las imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No se ve ninguna imagen o sólo ocurre con algunas? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo real de una de las imágenes que falla?

Comment: No muestra algunas, otras si. Puedo poner lo que haga falta pero no se a que te refieres con lo de poner un ejemplo real de la imagen que falla

Comment: Android es un sistema basado en UNIX/Linux y es sensible a mayúsculas/minúsculas. Parece que tus imágenes algunas están en minúsculas y otras en mayúsculas, entonces, por ejemplo, si haces `<img src="assets/imgs/pararazul.png">` la imagen no se verá porque su nombre es PARARAZUL.png que en Android no es lo mismo que pararazul.png. Esto podría ser el problema. En tus pruebas en el navegador en Windows (que no distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas) funcionará bien, pero al mover al dispositivo fallará. Con lo del ejemplo real me refería a que pongas el código de una de las imágenes que fallan.

Comment: El tema de mayúsculas y minúsculas lo he revisado también y nada, ahora pongo un ejemplo de una imagen que me muestra bien y una de la que no

Comment: Podría ser por utilizar las medidas vh en la imagen? aunque ahora veo que la que si que me muestra tiene el vh también

Comment: Según [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), las medidas vh en la imagen no deberían ser un problema (aunque igual te interesa no poner el CSS inline, pero eso no debería ser un problema). ¿Cómo generas el proyecto para probarlo en tu dispositivo?

Comment: Lo que hago para generar el apk es     ionic cordova resources       y después         ionic cordova build android

Comment: ¿En la consola de la DOM, te aparece algún error?. Si hay un error de que no encuentra la imagen, puede que tengas un problema de cache, se me ocurre. En mi caso me pasó algo parecido, limpié y funcionó.

Comment: Lo he solucionado cambiando la imagen, más bien, sacándola de la carpeta, cambiando el nombre y metiéndola en la carpeta otra vez, pero no veo el porqué ha pasado esto...